# Minimum Number of Possible Combinations to Predict Results of Double-Outcome Events

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are "n" different events. Each event can result in two possible outcomes (ie Yes or No). You make a guess for each event and list this (ie YYNYYNN for 7 events). To guarentee to correctly guess "x" out of "n", how many lists do you have to make minimum?

Comment: Solve this 'manually' for small numbers, like $n=1,2,3$ and search for a pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To solve manually you can only start with x=3, n=4 (because previous searches result as 2 because of combination of Y's and N's) which is I guess 4, for x=4, n=5 it is 8, but for n=6 and further values it gets out of hand to calculate manually.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking for the smallest size of [a binary covering code](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309081) of radius $R=n-x$.  Asymptotic bounds on this are known for constant or nearly constant $R$, but exact values generally appear to be difficult even when $R=1,x=n-1$.  However note the "perfect" cases of [Hamming codes](http://nuweb.neu.edu/bbarbiellini/int3470/sherman/coveringcodes.pdf), where $n=2^k-1$

Comment: A more updated [table for bounds on covering codes](http://www.sztaki.hu/~keri/codes/).